# HP TouchSmart tx2 pen with GIMP

Tags: gimp, touchsmart

How do I get GIMP to recognise the pen?
If I click on InputDevices/Extended... it tells me that it doesn't find any input devices.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I found it just worked out of the box for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wich OS? What version of the driver? Does it work in another applications? GIMP recognize my pen with no changes in the settings, but not the pen pressure. But that's another problem.